# In the Extension notes: for android java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor what is this?

Tags: android

```
 public class CustomScheduledExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

   static class CustomTask implements RunnableScheduledFuture { ... 

   protected  RunnableScheduledFuture decorateTask(
            Runnable r, RunnableScheduledFuture task) {
   return new CustomTask(r, task);
   }
```

Ive been trying to use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in an android app but it doesnt work the same as in a java app

```
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
   {

    Runnable runner = new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            rollthedice();

        }
    };


    if(view == continuous)
    {
    if(now == null)
        {now = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 0, 250,     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }
    else
        return;
    }
    if(view == stop)
    {
        if(now != null)
        {
            now.cancel(true);
            now = null;
        }

        else
            return;
    }
    if(view == roll)
        rollthedice();
    if(view == exit)
        System.exit(0);
   }
  }
```

this is my  code, i cannot get the continuous button to keep going, if it was a java app it would work fine

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do the behaviors differ? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i put my whole code on there, i want the continuous button to run rollthedice() continuously, it only runs it once in the background, it doesnt even upgrade the gui, you cant do it again unless you stop and hit the continuous button again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is that your `rollthedice()` method is scheduled on a non-UI thread and then tries to do a bunch of UI work. Android's UI objects are not thread-safe, so the behavior of cross-thread calls can be unexpected.

One solution would be to make a `continuousRunnable` that reposts itself to a `Handler` that's attached to the UI thread until some condition is met (e.g., the user presses "stop"):

```
Runnable continuousRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (stopPressed) {
            return;
        }
        rollthedice();

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 250);
    }
}
```

To get it running the first time, you can use the following:

```
mHandler.post(continuousRunnable);
```

To stop the `Runnable` from being reposted, use `removeCallbacks()`:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(continuousRunnable);
```

Comment: can you give me an example of how to construct mHandler?

Comment: You can initialize it with `mHandler = new Handler()` in (for example) your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: ok, thank you, continuous works but stop, how do i stop it, i cant stop it, is there mHandler."something" to put in the stop button

Comment: in the if i put stop.isPressed(), idk, this is my first time using a handler